# Degree of graph in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I were using `watts_strogatz network` from Networkx and get some data from it like degree of each node by `G.degree()`. I changed my graph to `grid_2d_graph` and now when I want to get degree of each node by `G.degree` , I get lots of errors .I don't know why ? they are both graphs from networkx . considering 20*20 `grid graph` and `watts_strogatz network` by 100 nodes . help me please .

Comment: Hi @yahya hematyar, welcome to stackoverflow, please add your code and also the errors message.

Comment: A [complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help get you a precise answer.  From the description so far it is hard to say, but perhaps you have made an assumption about the graph node names being integers in your code? `watts_strogatz_graph` does so (as do many others) but the 2d lattice uses (x,y) coordinates as the node names.